# How to change the size of a View dynamically in xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

In Xcode with Swift 5.
I have a view in which I placed Views and buttons below each other.
I set auto layout for all of them.
I wanted to change the size of the blue View, because data comes from the server.
How can I do it?
If I already use auto layout, can I no longer change the size at the code level?

[image: example]

Comment: You are talking about Views and setting AutoLayout. Is the question related to UIKit or SwiftUI?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I use UIKIt

Comment: Ok, can you also explain how you want to change the blue view? Like double its size, or so that it contains an image/text without cropping it, or what?

Comment: If everything is setup with constraints, then what do you need to change exactly? Your question needs a lot more details.

Comment: @web216 - ***of course*** you can change the size at code level. But... **why** you want to change it will determine **how** to change it. Is the "blue view" a `UILabel` (or a view holding a label) and you want it to change height based on its text? Or do you want it to get shorter when the red view/label has many lines of text? To get the best help, take a few minutes to explain what you are trying to do. Otherwise, we can only guess (which is often a big waste of time).

Comment: @web216 can you specify if there is any UILabel you are using in the Blue View??
If you are using an UILabel and there is no fixed height, then if you set the number of lines to 0 to the UILabel, it will automatically adjust the height.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a step-by-step guide on how to change the size of a view dynamically in Xcode with Swift 5:

**1. Create IBOutlet for the Constraint:**

Open your view controller file, and create an outlet for the height constraint of the blue view. Control-drag from the constraint to your view controller code to create the outlet.

```
@IBOutlet weak var blueViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

**2. Modify Constraint in Code:**

Whenever you need to change the size of the blue view (e.g., when data comes from the server), you can modify the constant value of the height constraint.

```
// Assuming newValue is the new height value you want to set
blueViewHeightConstraint.constant = newValue

// Animate the constraint change for a smoother transition (optional)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

**3. Update the UI:**

Make sure to call **`layoutIfNeeded`** to update the layout based on the modified constraint.

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

This will trigger the Auto Layout engine to recalculate the layout with the updated constraints.

By adjusting the constant of the height constraint, you effectively change the size of the blue view. Additionally, using **`layoutIfNeeded`** ensures that the changes are immediately reflected in the UI.